# Jquery isnt inputting some information into HTML doc

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a search function as a part of an online booking webapp I am writing that is done via AJAX request, when the search request is executed, the php doc/server does respond with the correct information:

```
<tr class='hover'>
    <td class='files fileName'/> result1 </td> 
    <td class='owner files name green' >Available</td> 
</tr>
<tr class='hover'> 
    <td class='files fileName'/> result2 </td> 
    <td class='owner files name green' >Available</td> 
</tr>
<tr class='hover'> 
    <td class='files fileName'/> result3 </td> 
    <td class='owner files name green' >Available</td> 
</tr>
```

However, if I inspect element, I get this:

```
<tr class='hover'>
    <td class='files fileName'/></td> 
    <td class='owner files name green' >Available</td> 
</tr>
<tr class='hover'> 
    <td class='files fileName'/></td> 
    <td class='owner files name green' >Available</td> 
</tr>
<tr class='hover'> 
    <td class='files fileName'/></td> 
    <td class='owner files name green' >Available</td> 
</tr>
```

notice that in the second example, the second line for each `<tr>` does not have a result in the `<td>`

my jquery code looks like this,

```
$("#table").empty(); //to empty the rable of default results
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        $("#table").html(xhttp.responseText); //should put the new data into the table
        console.log(xhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

why does jquery omit only those values? seems to precise to be random, but its in the middle of the string so that doesnt make any sense.

Comment: try without xhttp

Comment: could you elaborate? @Vishwa

Comment: `<tag/>` is a self-closing tag. It means that it has no body and it has no closing tag. Remove the slashes at the end of your opening `<td>`'s. (So `<td class='files fileName'/>` --> `<td class='files fileName'>`)

Comment: @Ivar thanks, that fixed it, I can't believe I was trying to fix this for like 3 hours lol.

Answer (score 0):

I now fixed the issue, this is how I did it.

TL;DR, I was stupid

I accidentally added a closing `/` to the end of my `<td>` so that it became `td class='files fileName'/>` which lead to complications.

thanks to user Ivar for pointing this out to me